# How to inject mocks with Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I want to inject a mock into my Springboot application. I get this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'ca.company.TestA': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'a'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ca.company.hello.A' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I'm stuck and don't understand how to process. I Defined `A` to be autowired. What's the problem?

Here is my test file:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestA {

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    private B Bmock;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Bmock = Mockito.mock(B.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(a, "b", Bmock);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSpeak() {
        when(Bmock.writeToScreen()).thenReturn("Everything will be alright");
        assert(true);
    }
}
```

here is the config file:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B();
    }

    // The error persists whether I define this bean or not
    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A();
    }

}
```

And here is the class in question:

```
@Component
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;



    public void speak() {
        System.out.println(b.writeToScreen());
    }
}
```

And finally here is my file structure:

[image]

What am I doing wrong, I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration class is not processed by Spring. The simplest way to achieve that is to put `@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)` in your test class.